# Remove "Except for the accepted answer" from the "Vote up" page in the help center

Tags: bug, status-review, help-center

Some time ago, Stack Exchange changed how the order of the answers are. They used to be sorted by accepted answer, then votes. Now it's only sorted by votes. The help center however still says this on the [upvote privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) page:

> When you vote up, you are moving that content "up" so it will be seen by more people. 
> By default, answers are sorted by number of votes. 
> ... 
> Except for the accepted answer, which appears first unless it was written by the asker.

However this isn't true anymore. Can the last part be removed, and maybe take out "By default" in the second line?

Comment: This page is the same across all SE sites. If possible, this should be configured to reflect the site in question's preference.