# Outdated information about accepted answer pinning on "Vote Up" privileges page

Tags: bug, help-center

The [Vote Up privileges help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) currently reads:

> ### What happens when I vote up posts?
>
> When you vote up, you are moving that content "up" so it will be seen by more people.
>
> - By default, answers are sorted by number of votes.<sup>1</sup>
> - Upvotes on a question give the asker +10 reputation.
> - Upvotes on an answer give the answerer +10 reputation.
> - You can vote on posts 30 times per UTC day, plus 10 more times on questions only.
>
> <sup>1</sup>Except for the accepted answer, which appears first unless
> it was written by the asker.

The superscript and accompanying footnote should be removed, as an accepted answer is [no longer pinned](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/411352/15497888) and does not appear first unless it is also the highest scoring answer.

Comment: Cross-dupe: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/375423/1088098

Comment: Duplicate: [Remove "Except for the accepted answer" from the "Vote up" page in the help center](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/413106/remove-except-for-the-accepted-answer-from-the-vote-up-page-in-the-help-cent)